# How do I programatically resize a component in a BorderLayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, border-layout

I have a JPanel that is located at the BorderLayout.SOUTH position of a parent JPanel.  I would like to programatically change the height of this child JPanel.

I am calling `childPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(getWidth(), newHeight));`, but it has no effect.  (I have tried setting the Maximum and Minimum sizes as well.)

What (probably very simple thing) am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After changing the preferred size, you need to call [revalidate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#revalidate%28%29) on that childPanel.

You may want to read this [Oracle Tutorial on LayoutManagers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)

Comment: in some cases could be used pack() +1

Comment: Thanks, I knew it would be something easy!